# How do I get jooq to generate Double instead of BigDecimal?

Tags: jooq

My database types are:

```
    price decimal(5,2) not null,
    servings decimal(3,2) not null,
```

Jooq generates BigDecimal for these, despite them clearly being within range of Double. I tried using a ForcedType, at least as ChatGPT suggested it (the manual is impenetrable re ForcedTypes):

```
                        .withInputSchema("public")
                        .withForcedTypes(listOf(ForcedType()
                            .withName("DOUBLE")
                            .withExpression(".*")
                            .withTypes("DECIMAL")
                        ))
                    )
```

...but this didn't work either (and jooq printed out a warning.)

Answer (score 0):

> Jooq generates BigDecimal for these, despite them clearly being within range of Double

I think there's a misunderstanding about the purpose of these data types:

- SQL's `NUMERIC` / `NUMBER` / `DECIMAL` types are designed for an accurate representation of decimal numbers, as is usually required in all kinds of accounting, banking systems, etc. where monetary amounts (or other kinds of legal amounts) require an accurate representation. In Java, that's `BigDecimal`
- SQL `DOUBLE PRECISION`, `FLOAT`, `REAL` types are designed for faster computation where losses of accuracy are acceptable, e.g. for scientific data, graphical data, etc. In Java, that's `Double` or `Float`

They're not directly interchangeable, so it would be very unwise for jOOQ to do what you're expecting it to do out of the box, just because things are in some perceived range. I actually doubt you're doing the right thing here, given that one of your fields is about a `price`!

> at least as ChatGPT suggested it (the manual is impenetrable re ForcedTypes)

ChatGPT mostly learns jOOQ from jOOQ's manual, probably, so it must have found this section useful:

- [Data type rewriting](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-rewrite/)

Maybe, you'll find it useful as well? The regular expressions are case sensitive. Your usage of lower case `public` seems to suggest you're using PostgreSQL, so perhaps also use lower case identifiers for data types? If you want to play safe, just use `(?i:decimal)`. The rest should work